# LDAP finds user, but "permission denied" when logging in

Tags: redhat, openldap, pam, sssd

I am setting up an LDAP client in Red Hat 8.

After setting up the config files I did an LDAP user test and it came back successfully:

```
# id myusername
uid=666(myusername) gid=510(active_users) groups=510(active_users)
```

If I run an `ldapsearch` it returns successfully with the expected results:

```
# ldapsearch -x -ZZ -h ldap.example.com -b dc=example,dc=com
```

But if I try to `ssh` to the Red Hat 8 machine from another machine then I get this error:

```
# ssh myusername@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
myusername@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I have tried a couple of different machines with different user accounts and have gotten the same results.

Here is my setup:

### /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

```
[domain/default]
ldap_tls_reqcert = demand
cache_credentials = False
ldap_search_base = dc=example,dc=com
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap
ldap_uri = ldaps://ldap.example.com/
ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/sssd/ca-bundle.crt

[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, ssh
domains = default

[nss]
homedir_substring = /home
```

### /etc/openldap/ldap.conf

```
TLS_CACERT /etc/sssd/ca-bundle.crt

#BASE dc=example,dc=com
#URI ldap://ldap.example.com/
SASL_NOCANON    on
URI ldaps://ldap.example.com/
BASE dc=example,dc=com
TLS_CACERTDIR /etc/sssd
```

### /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
# Generated by authselect on Thu Jan 27 15:22:08 2022
# Do not modify this file manually.

passwd:     sss files systemd
group:      sss files systemd
netgroup:   sss files
automount:  sss files
services:   sss files

# passwd:    db files
# shadow:    db files
# group:     db files

# In order of likelihood of use to accelerate lookup.
shadow:     files sss
hosts:      files dns myhostname

aliases:    files
ethers:     files
gshadow:    files
# Allow initgroups to default to the setting for group.
# initgroups: files
networks:   files dns
protocols:  files
publickey:  files
rpc:        files
```

### /etc/sysconfig/authconfig

```
USELDAP=yes
USELDAPAUTH=yes
```

### /etc/pam.d/password-auth

```
# Generated by authselect on Thu Jan 27 15:22:08 2022
# Do not modify this file manually.

auth        required                                     pam_env.so
auth        required                                     pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_usertype.so isregular
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_localuser.so
auth        sufficient                                   pam_unix.so nullok
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_usertype.so isregular
auth        sufficient                                   pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth        required                                     pam_deny.so

account     required                                     pam_unix.so
account     sufficient                                   pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient                                   pam_usertype.so issystem
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required                                     pam_permit.so

password    requisite                                    pam_pwquality.so local_users_only
password    sufficient                                   pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok use_authtok
password    sufficient                                   pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required                                     pam_deny.so

session     optional                                     pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required                                     pam_limits.so
-session    optional                                     pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore]                   pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required                                     pam_unix.so
session     optional                                     pam_sss.so
```

### /etc/pam.d/system-auth

```
# Generated by authselect on Thu Jan 27 15:22:08 2022
# Do not modify this file manually.

auth        required                                     pam_env.so
auth        required                                     pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_usertype.so isregular
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_localuser.so
auth        sufficient                                   pam_unix.so nullok
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_usertype.so isregular
auth        sufficient                                   pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth        required                                     pam_deny.so

account     required                                     pam_unix.so
account     sufficient                                   pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient                                   pam_usertype.so issystem
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required                                     pam_permit.so

password    requisite                                    pam_pwquality.so local_users_only
password    sufficient                                   pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok use_authtok
password    sufficient                                   pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required                                     pam_deny.so

session     optional                                     pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required                                     pam_limits.so
-session    optional                                     pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore]                   pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required                                     pam_unix.so
session     optional                                     pam_sss.so
```

### /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
# $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
PermitRootLogin yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#GSSAPIEnablek5users no

UsePAM yes

X11Forwarding yes

# It is recommended to use pam_motd in /etc/pam.d/sshd instead of PrintMotd,
# as it is more configurable and versatile than the built-in version.
PrintMotd no

ClientAliveInterval 600
ClientAliveCountMax 0

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

### /var/log/secure

```
Jan 28 08:35:39 opal sshd[206875]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  user=myusername
Jan 28 08:35:40 opal sshd[206875]: Failed password for myusername from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 60384 ssh2
```

### Attempts

I have tried the following:

- Disabling selinux in `/etc/selinux/config`
- Stopping iptables.service
- Adding `PermitRootLogin yes` and `UsePAM yes` to the Red Hat 8 `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf` file
- Repeatedly tried `authselect select sssd`, and then restarting sssd.service
- Adding `FORCELEGACY=yes` in `/etc/sysconfig/authconfig`

### Question

Can anyone help me figure out why users cannot use SSH to log in to this server?

Comment: Have you tried logging in to *both* systems as a *non-LDAP* user, and doing the `id` command on both? That would identify if it's a domain joining issue, or something else.

Comment: @shearn89 I have logged in as a non-LDAP user and performed the `id` command on the Red Hat machine. From the machines that I am trying to SSH from, I am able to SSH to other machines using LDAP users.

Comment: Sorry, is the Red Hat machine the server or client? Can you test the `id` command on BOTH server and client.

Comment: The Red Hat machine is a server. Yes, the `id` command works on both the server and the client.

Comment: Is time in sync between both?

Comment: Good question, I checked and yes they are in sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution, by creating a custom `authselect` profile with custom `password-auth`, `system-auth`, and `nsswitch.conf` files.

**1. Create custom profile based off sssd**

```
authselect create-profile user-profile -b sssd
```

**2. Overwrite `/etc/authselect/custom/user-profile/password-auth` and `/etc/authselect/custom/user-profile/system-auth` with the following settings**

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_sss.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     sufficient    pam_sss.so
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

**3. Overwrite `/etc/authselect/custom/user-profile/nsswitch.conf` with the following settings**

```
passwd:     files sss     {exclude if "with-custom-passwd"}
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss     {exclude if "with-custom-group"}
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
netgroup:   files sss     {exclude if "with-custom-netgroup"}
automount:  files sss     {exclude if "with-custom-automount"}
services:   files sss     {exclude if "with-custom-services"}
sudoers:    files sss     {exclude if "with-sudo"}
```

**4. Select new profile**

```
authselect select custom/user-profile
```

**5. Restart sssd**

```
systemctrl restart sssd
```